# Can FindVisualChildren locate GridViewColumns of a ListView? If not, how can they be addressed?

Tags: wpf, listview

Can FindVisualChildren locate GridViewColumns of a ListView? In my code-behind below a click on the button (after the listview is fully displayed, with columns all populated etc) always returns 0. The xmal code is not interesting, so I haven't included. Just a listview with gridview as a view.

FindLogicalChildren doesn't seem to do any better. My reading on this was inconclusive. There seemed be some debate.

The ultimate purpose here is to expand the width of the column when a user clicks a button. Various MVVM attempts at this ended in frustration. A code-behind approach should work, but the named GridViewColumns can't be addressed directly, hence this visualchildren approach. How do I dig them out?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 var thechildren = FindVisualChildren<GridViewColumn>(SectionListView);
 MessageBox.Show(thechildren.Count().ToString());
}

public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any possibility to get current `GridViewColumn` with `VisualTreeHelper` or `LogicalTreeHelper`. *"xmal code is not interesting, so I haven't included"* - xaml code is very interesting because you can solve it in xaml. You just need to pass the reference of the current `GridViewColumn` to the event handler. You can do it e.g. via `Button.Tag` property:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.Columns>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="col1">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="gridViewButton" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding ElementName=col1}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if((sender as Button)?.Tag is GridViewColumn gvc)
    {
        gvc.Width = 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx! By "xmal code is not interesting" I didn't mean not useful, just that it was completely generic. But point taken!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to the question about GridViewColumns as VisualChildren, but I was able to get a code-behind solution going along the following lines, where the
View is TimeTableView (containing the ListView/GridView), the ViewModel is TimeTableViewModel and StaffColumnWidth a ViewModel property bound to the column width. Kind of clunky, but it works.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
var vm = DataContext as  TimeTableViewModel;
vm.StaffColumnWidth=100;
}
```